# Getting screen width without using SurfaceHolder

Tags: java, android, height, width, screen

How do I get the phone's width or height without using SurfaceHolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```